# Send event across Windows Remote Desktop session back to local computer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, azure, outlook, remoteapp

I have a program running on my company's remote terminal services box (**Windows Server 2012 R2 - Azure environment**) that the call-center operators of the software use RemoteApp to access.

The effect I'm trying to achieve is for the call-center employees to be able to double click on a grid on a form containing a customer's email addresses on the program they access via RemoteApp and have it open their **local** MS Outlook and pre-populate a new email message window's "To:" line with the email address they double clicked on in the remotely hosted program.

I realize there is a lot to unpack here, but **in general, is it possible to have an event triggered from a remotely hosted application transmitted back to the local computer and have it act on it?** And more specifically, have MS Outlook 2016 open a new message window with the correct email address.

**My limitations are:**

The remote software of which I'm a developer was built on a limited
market proprietary platform that sits on top of MS SQL Server 2012, and event
handlers in this platform are coded in workflow that triggers SQL
code. So SQL Server is the system where I'm afforded the most
flexibility to work with whatever tools are available.

Alternatively, event handler workflow can contain VB.Net
"script-blocks", with which I'm far less likely to have the
flexibility to use whatever APIs may be available to achieve this,
but if anyone knows of a solution this way, I'd like to hear it.

Much obliged.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, I've recently had success implementing a solution involving a CLR function, so the illimitable possibilities of C#.Net and all external libraries **may** be an option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can develop a COM add-in which can communicate with your remote software. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).